# What is the difference between [u8] and Vec<u8> on rust?

Tags: rust

What is the difference between `[u8]` and `Vec<u8>` on rust?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`[u8]` represents an unsized contiguous sequence of `u8`. Since its size is unknown at compile time, you can't store it in a variable because a variable needs a fixed size. You cannot pass it to or return it from functions for the same reason, so it's not very useful on its own. The primary use of a slice type like `[u8]` is to create slice references (like `&[u8]`), smart pointers (like `Box<[u8]>`), and in generic types (like `AsRef<[u8]>`). `str` wraps (consists of) a `[u8]` but only allows valid UTF-8.

`&[u8]` is a "slice reference" which refers to such a sequence, and also carries information about its length. The reference is represented by a "fat pointer" two machine words wide, consisting of pointer to the data and the length of the data. It's the basis for `&str`.

`Box<[u8]>` is like `&[u8]`, except it owns the underlying memory, i.e. the underlying octet sequence is heap-allocated by `Box::new()` and deallocated on `Drop`. Just like `&[u8]`, it is two machine words wide. It's the basis for `Box<str>`.

`Vec<u8>` is like `Box<[u8]>`, except it additionally stores a "capacity" count, making it three machine words wide. Separately stored capacity allows for efficient resizing of the underlying sequence. It's the basis for `String`.